# Call to a Superclass function which alters a component (label)

Tags: c#, winforms, class, inheritance

If a Superclass has a function A() which changes a Label to "Hello World". How can I get a subclass to call A() with the same result? As of now, I get no compile error, but the text won't change!

Example code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FunctionA("Hello");
    }  

    public void FunctionA(string s)
    {
        label1.Text = s;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}

class Test : Form1
{
    public Test()
    {
        FunctionA("World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Button2_Click is creating a new form instance.  Are you expecting to change the label in the same form instance as button2 ?

Comment: Yes I realized that :/ Yes exactly. I want the subclass to trigger FunctionA of the Superclass

Comment: A base class should NEVER know of it's subclasses.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish ?  It sounds like you are trying to implemented a visitor pattern

Comment: @RobertSlaney  I have a ListView on Form A. And an Update() function. I want to call Update from another class. Like I want to trigger Update() to run. I can call it from a Subclass, but program crashes if I do. If I call Update() from Form A, it works. It doesnt have to be a subclass.. I just thought it was a good idea... Was thinking of making Update() static, but then i get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `Forms` must be having their own `Label` control to display messages. You might be using one `Label` to show the message which is not part of displaying `Form`.

I am not sure what are to trying to achieve but why don't you just pass the `Label` control to FunctionA to modify the message this way:

```
public void FunctionA(ref Label lbl, string s)
{
    lbl.Text = s;
}
```

**ADDED:** You can do it this way:

1. First creating the instance of `FormA`.

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       //...
       FormA frmA = new FormA();
       Application.Run(frmA);
   }
   ```
2. Passing the instance of `FormA` to `FormB` by exposing a parameterized constructor for any manipulation in `FormA` from within `FormB`.

   ```
   FormB frmB = new FormB(frmA);

   //...

   public partial class FormB : Form
   {
       public FormB()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       //parameterized constructor
       public FormB(FormA obj)
       {
           FormA = obj;
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public FormA FormA { get; set; }   
   }
   ```

Comment: Hm, could be.. but I want to change the Label of the superclass.. from another class (preferable a subclass?). How do I achieve that?

Comment: Why by ref?  Passing by value will achieve the same result.  This would allow the Label to be re-assigned, not just the text.  I would strongly avoid passing anything by ref.

Comment: Ah, nice one! Thanks! But. This works for a label. But let's say FunctionA is a bit more complex.. and gets data from SQL and adds to a TreeView. Then, how would I call FunctionA, without getting a null reference error?

Comment: @Half_Baked, Why are you afraid of Null reference exception, is there any possibility of it?

Comment: @FSX The thing is. I have a ListView of Form A. And an Update() function. I want to call Update from another class. Like I want to trigger Update() to run. I can call it from a Subclass, but program crashes if I do. If I call Update() from Form A, it works

Comment: If you already have an instance of Form A, and the method is public, just invoke it.  You need to be mindful of any UI updates if your NOT on the UI thread

Comment: It should also work fine if you call the Update() function on the instance of FormA even from another Form.

Comment: Well I don't have an instance of Form A as of now Application.Run(new FormA()); But I guess I could do FormA formA and Run(formA). Then I could call formA.Update() from Form B ?

Comment: Yes this is the better way to do it.

Comment: Tried it, but can't. "object reference is required for non static-field" ... static void Main(). I have to define it somewhere so i can make FormA forma public or internal...

Comment: Hmm.. I can't get it to work :( FormB frmB = new FormB(frmA); I cant do this, since frmA is not global... ?

Comment: Introduce the parameterized constructor in FormB class, see my edited answer.

Comment: I dropped FormB to be a form. Also, no inheritance. What do you think of an delegate? So classB can call update() on FormA ?

Comment: I would prefer to update your question first. Second, you can call the Update() of FormA from within ClassB as long as you have the instance of FormA for which you want to call Update to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your forms before running the main form.  Assign the form1 reference to form2

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
        new Form2() { Form1 = mainForm }.Show();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1 Form1 { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Form1.Update("World");
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Update("Hello");
    }

    public void Update(string text)
    {
        this.label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```